# Merging zoo object using do.call in R

Tags: r, merge, zoo, do.call

A have several csv file like this :

```
,timestamp,AirTemperature_House
    1,2013-09-01 00:00:00,8.22
    2,2013-09-01 01:00:00,6.53
    3,2013-09-01 02:00:00,6.67
    4,2013-09-01 03:00:00,5.58
    5,2013-09-01 04:00:00,4.16
    6,2013-09-01 05:00:00,4.76
    7,2013-09-01 06:00:00,5.06
    8,2013-09-01 07:00:00,5.16
    9,2013-09-01 08:00:00,6.83
    10,2013-09-01 09:00:00,8.59
    11,2013-09-01 10:00:00,10.99
    12,2013-09-01 11:00:00,11.08
```

I grouped them to a list of zoo object using the following code :

```
raw_data<-list.files(path = "./AWS_Data_STU/Air_temp/",pattern="Air",full.names = T)

data_stu<-lapply(raw_data,function(x){
   ss<-read.csv(x)

  ss<-zoo(ss,order.by = ss$timestamp)


})
```

I made a list of zoo object which all look like this one :

```
str(data_stu[[1]])

    ‘zoo’ series from 2013-09-01 00:00:00 to 2014-04-30 23:00:00
      Data: num [1:5808] 8.22 6.53 6.67 5.58 4.16 4.76 5.06 5.16 6.83 8.59 ...
      Index:  Factor w/ 5808 levels "2013-09-01 00:00:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

...

I want to merge all my list to a data frame as :

```
X1  x2  x3  X4 x5 x6  x7
1 12.95    NA NA NA    
2 14.81 14.37 NA NA 12.78 NA 
3 15.02 15.11 NA NA 12.61 NA 
4 13.91 14.25 NA NA 11.89 NA 
5 12.34 13.96 NA NA 10.86 NA 
6 14.40 14.47 NA NA 10.40 NA
```

I used the do call function

```
do.call(merge.zoo,data_stu )

    structure(c(7.66, 7.29, 7.34, 7.15, 6.76, 6.41, 6.25, 6.36, 6.78, 
    1                                                                    NA
    2                                                                    NA
    3                                                                    NA
    4                                                                    NA
    5                                                                    NA
    6                                                                    NA
    7                                                                    NA
    8
```

but it gave me only NA object.

Any ideas ?

Comment: please use `dput()` to share data.

Comment: I did it in R, but i can't find how to put the ascii file on this site. Sorry I am a new user.

Comment: Use `dput(head(data_stu[1:4], 30))`, then copy and paste the results into your question. The output is ugly looking, but allows others to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, i put an sample of my data in a recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the index of all your zoo objects are factors. You need to convert them to `POSIXct`. Also, you should not call methods directly. I.e., you should call `merge` instead of `merge.zoo` and let R handle method dispatch.

You can also use `read.zoo` to help with the conversion.

```
data_stu <- do.call(merge, lapply(raw_data, read.zoo, sep=",", header=TRUE,
    FUN=as.POSIXct, colClasses=c("NULL", "character", "numeric")))
```